# Firestore is taking to long to sync data when Android device comes online again

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The process is simple. My android is listening to the Firestore database changes with the following method:

```
    final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("collection").document("123");
    docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                return;
            }

            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                message.setText(snapshot.getData().get("status").toString());
            } else {
                Log.d("", "Current data: null");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This method is on the `onCreate` method of my activity. This works just fine. When I update the value "status" on Firestore, it updates immediately on my Android Device.

However, when I turn off my wi-fi and 3G, update the data on Firestore, and turn on the wi-fi and 3G again, it takes about 2 minutes to sync data again. The listener takes this long to "hear" what is new on the Firestore database. Is this the correct behavior? Or Am I missing something?